# How to Add tab space to multilple line at the same time in any text editor

Tags: sublimetext, text-editor, geany, keyboard-shortcuts

If you select a text you can add multiple tab spaces to the all lines simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the answer from kelgwiin for sublime text.

Depending on your platform you could also do the following in sublime text:

**Linux**: Hold `shift` and the `right mouse button`, then move the mouse up or down to make a column selection.

**Windows** + **OS X**: Simply hold down the `mousewheel` and move your mouse up and and down to select the columns.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

For that you must select the `n` lines of the code and press the key `tab`. If you want 
remove the tab spaces should select the text and press `shift+tab`.

I was programming in my job and I accidentally discovered this in the IDE eclipse. I test the same process
in the Sublime Text and  Geany and it works too.

Y suposse and pressume that works for the most of text editor

Answer (score 1):

On Geany you can create by using Alt+Shift+Mouse (Windows) or Ctrl-Shift-Mouse (*x) a multiline cursor or an rectange selection, where you can work on many lines at the same time. This is only working for lines 'in row' so you cannot choose line 9 and lines 12-16 and lines 23-44 to be edited at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the command is `ctrl+shift+mouse`.

Comment: Sorry. It's differing between Windows and *X for §reasons.

Comment: Oks. Dont worry about that. Anyway thanks for your answer. And my SI is Linus Mint and too Windows 7.